# jq doesn't inject value into the json file

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have json file `env.json` having following content:

```
{
  "parameters": {
    "name": "www",
    "dev" : "",
    "prod": ""
  }
}
```

Now I want to inject values of `dev` and `prod` via a bash script using `jq`. Here's the code:

```
  ENVJSON=$(cat env.json)
  jq '.parameters.name = $val' --arg val $NAME <<<"$ENVJSON" > env.json
  jq '.parameters.prod = $val' --arg val $PROD <<<"$ENVJSON" > env.json
  jq '.parameters.dev = $val'  --arg val $DEV  <<<"$ENVJSON" > env.json
```

When I run this, I get the values of $NAME and $DEV correctly injected into the JSON file. But the $PROD value doesn't get injected for the `prod` index. It stays empty. Looks like this is an issue with the middle line.

If I swap the last two lines, then yes, the middle line doesn't work.

What could be wrong here?

---

I also tried appending `&& sleep 1` at end of each `jq` command, no luck.

Comment: All three commands are given the same JSON string as input and write the result to the same file, overwriting the previous one's output.

Comment: Oops, that's so dumb of me...

Comment: Why did you think `sleep`ing at the end of each command would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the last use of `jq` is given the original `env.json` rather than the one modified by the earlier uses of `jq`. We can solve this problem by only invoking `jq` once (getting a performance boost as a bonus).

```sh
ENVJSON="$( cat env.json )"
jq \
   --arg name "$NAME" \
   --arg prod "$PROD" \
   --arg dev  "$DEV"  \
'
  .parameters.name = $name |
  .parameters.prod = $prod |
  .parameters.dev  = $dev
' <<<"$ENVJSON" >env.json
```

If the variables are exported, we can even use

```sh
jq '
  .parameters.name = env.name |
  .parameters.prod = env.prod |
  .parameters.dev  = env.dev
'
```

---

By the way, `sponge` is great for reading and writing from the same file.

```sh
jq '...' env.json | sponge env.json
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a multi-value replacement with `jq` to prevent overwriting the same file again and again.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
NAME=name
DEV=dev
PROD=prod
echo -e "$(jq --arg name $NAME --arg dev $DEV --arg prod $PROD '.parameters.name = ($name) | .parameters.dev = ($dev) | .parameters.prod = ($prod)' env.json)" > env.json
```

Comment: What's with the `-e` argument to echo?

Comment: (Sorry about the edit, I don't know how, but I completely misread. It's been reverted. Not an excuse, but maybe if the had made the command more readable instead of hiding most of it off the screen...)

Comment: @ikegami - It's not required here. Being a programmer, that's how I always `echo` to interpret the escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

It is not needed to read the JSON template from a file if it never changes. The template is incorporated in the `jq` filter script that takes a `--null-input` or `-n`, so it can directly be written to the output file, without saving to an intermediate temporary file.

```sh
NAME='www foo' PROD='prod bar thing' DEV='stuff for dev baz'
jq -n --arg name "$NAME" --arg prod "$PROD" --arg dev "$DEV" \
  '{"parameters":{"name":$name,"dev":$dev,"prod":$prod}}' > env.json
```

`cat env.json`:

```json
{
  "parameters": {
    "name": "www foo",
    "dev": "stuff for dev baz",
    "prod": "prod bar thing"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are great, but I made a dumb mistake which I want to point out. In these commands,

```
  ENVJSON=$(cat env.json)
  jq '.parameters.name = $val' --arg val $NAME <<<"$ENVJSON" > env.json
  jq '.parameters.prod = $val' --arg val $PROD <<<"$ENVJSON" > env.json
  jq '.parameters.dev = $val'  --arg val $DEV  <<<"$ENVJSON" > env.json
```

I was using the same input in each of these commands, not the updated one. So I changed it to:

```
  jq '.parameters.name = $val' --arg val $NAME <<<"$(cat env.json)" > env.json
  jq '.parameters.prod = $val' --arg val $PROD <<<"$(cat env.json)" > env.json
  jq '.parameters.dev = $val'  --arg val $DEV  <<<"$(cat env.json)" > env.json
```

and it worked.